# Trying to rewrite a C# Script into Python, not working

Tags: c#, python, python-2.7

I'm trying to convert a C# script into Python. Here's what the C# Program looks like.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

class Encoder
{
    public static string encodeLength(int value, int length)
    {
        string stack = "";
        for (int x = 1; x <= length; x++)
        {
            int offset = 6 * (length - x);
            byte val = (byte)(64 + (value >> offset & 0x3f));
            stack += (char)val;
        }
        return stack;
    }
    public static string encodeLength(string Val)
    {
        int value = Val.Length;
        int length = 2;
        string stack = "";
        for (int x = 1; x <= length; x++)
        {
            int offset = 6 * (length - x);
            byte val = (byte)(64 + (value >> offset & 0x3f));
            stack += (char)val;
        }
        return stack;
    }
    public static string encodeLength(int value)
    {
        int length = 2;
        string stack = "";
        for (int x = 1; x <= length; x++)
        {
            int offset = 6 * (length - x);
            byte val = (byte)(64 + (value >> offset & 0x3f));
            stack += (char)val;
        }
        return stack;
    }
}
```

This is the stuff that I get returned when I call `Encoder.encodeLength(55) + Encoder.encodeLength("Testing.".Length) + "Testing.` in C#.

```
@w@HTesting.
```

Here's what I've written in Python so far.

```
def encodeLength(*args):
    if len(args) == 2 and isinstance(args[0] and args[1], int):
        i = 1
        stack = str()
        while (i <= length):
            offset = 6 * (length - i)
            x = 64 + (value >> offset & 0x3f)
            stack += str(x)
            i +=1
        return stack

    elif len(args) == 1 and isinstance(args[0], str):
        i = 1
        value = args[0]
        length = 2
        stack = str()
        while (i <= length):
            offset = 6 * (length - i)
            x = 64 + (value >> offset & 0x3f)
            stack += str(x)
            i += 1
        return stack

    elif len(args) == 1 and isinstance(args[0], int):
        i = 1
        length = 2
        stack = str()
        while (i <= length):
            offset = 6 * (length - i)
            x = 64 + (args[0] >> offset & 0x3f)
            stack += str(x)
            i +=1
        return stack
```

This is my response in Python when I call `encodeLength(55) + encodeLength(len("Testing.")) + "Testing."`.

```
641196472Testing.
```

Does anyone know why this isn't returning the output generated by C#?

Comment: where does `length` come from?

Comment: Also, in the C# example your second struing is "Testing"  in the python example, your string is "Testing."  you have an extra character.

Comment: WombatPM: That was a type, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, `str(x)` does not convert a char code (ASCII value) into the corresponding char. Use `chr(x)` to achieve this. `str(x)` converts objects into strings, meaning that the ASCII code `64` is turned into the string `"64"`, rather than into `"@"`, which is what `chr(x)` returns.